# How can I combine datetime.date and datetime.time columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Given df

```
          Date      Time    Data     
3   2017-08-10  15:15:00    a    
0   2017-08-11  15:15:00    b    
1   2017-08-12  15:15:00    c    
2   2017-08-13  15:15:00    d    
1   2017-08-14  15:15:00    e
```

And

```
print (type(df['Date'].iat[0]))
<class 'datetime.date'>

print (type(df['Time'].iat[0]))
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

How can I combine df.Date and df.Time into a DateTime column that is a datetime object ??:

```
        Date        Time    Data  DateTime   
3   2017-08-10  15:15:00    a     2017-08-10 15:15:00
0   2017-08-11  15:15:00    b     2017-08-11 15:15:00
1   2017-08-12  15:15:00    c     2017-08-12 15:15:00
2   2017-08-13  15:15:00    d     2017-08-13 15:15:00
1   2017-08-14  15:15:00    e     2017-08-14 15:15:00
```

What I tried:

```
df['DateTime'] = df.apply(lambda r : pd.datetime.combine(r['Date'],r['Time']),1)
```

This works well as intended, However, I would prefer a vectorized operation and I get the following msg:

```
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:1: 
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that both date and time are already in datetime format. Try

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + df['Time'].astype(str), format = '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')
```

Though I don't know if it would be more efficient than using datetime.combine

Comment: I tried this before but I get:  "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str'"

Comment: I tested and its working, what version are you on? You can also try the alternative approach I added

Comment: The alternative version gives me this: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.time'

Comment: version Pandas 0.19.2

Comment: I am sorry I missed the part that the columns are already in datetime format. Pl see the changes.

Comment: The issue persists, with your last suggestion I get: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Hmm, you should have got that error only if the date column was not in datetime format

Comment: It's confirmed <class 'datetime.date'>

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party... Vaishali's answer works if "Date" is a datetime-like object.

`str(date)` will give `yyyy-mm-dd` output [according to docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.__str__), so you can do:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str) + df['Time'].astype(str), format = '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')
```

However, I have not tested this for speed.