# Combine pandas df [datetime] time and date columns into one datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I'm a bit confused trying to combine pandas DataFrame columns with datetime.date format and datetime.time format.
DF looks like this:

```
    VJNo    VJIdx   lnTime  lnDate
0   32613   1   05:00:00    2023-04-18
1   32613   2   05:01:00    2023-04-18
2   32613   3   05:02:30    2023-04-18
3   32613   5   05:05:30    2023-04-18
4   32613   6   05:06:30    2023-04-18
5   32613   8   05:07:30    2023-04-18
6   32613   9   05:08:30    2023-04-18
7   32613   11  05:10:30    2023-04-18
```

I wanted to use [pandas.Timestamp.combine(date, time)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.combine.html), but apparently it doesn't want to work for DataSeries...(?) Running:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Defining the data
data = {'VJNo': [32613, 32613, 32613, 32613, 32613, 32613, 32613, 32613],
        'VJIdx': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11],
        'lnTime': ['05:00:00', '05:01:00', '05:02:30', '05:05:30', '05:06:30', '05:07:30', '05:08:30', '05:10:30'],
        'lnDate': ['2023-04-18', '2023-04-18', '2023-04-18', '2023-04-18', '2023-04-18', '2023-04-18', '2023-04-18', '2023-04-18']}

# Create pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['tmp'] = pd.Timestamp.combine( df['lnDate'], df['lnTime'])
```

Returns error: `combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not Series`, while it is `datetime.date`, but series of it...
Unfortunately other solutions like found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681873/how-can-i-combine-datetime-date-and-datetime-time-columns-in-pandas-dataframe) also doesn't work (probably due to changes in pandas):

```py
df['tmp'] = df.apply(pd.Timestamp.combine, df['lnDate'], df['lnTime'])
```

or

```py
df['tmp'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp.combine(x['lnDate'], x['lnTime']))
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Last resort would be probably to convert date and time to strings and then use `pd.to_datetime` on them, but... I think it's not the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) your function:

```
import numpy as np

f = np.vectorize(pd.Timestamp.combine)
# f = np.vectorize(lambda d,t: pd.Timestamp.combine(d, t))

dfP['out'] = f(dfP['lnDate'], dfP['lnTime'])
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
dfP['out'] = [pd.Timestamp(d, t) for d, t in zip(df['lnDate'], df['lnTime'])]
```

Output:

```
    VJNo  VJIdx    lnTime      lnDate                 out
0  32613      1  05:00:00  2023-04-18 2023-04-18 05:00:00
1  32613      2  05:01:00  2023-04-18 2023-04-18 05:01:00
2  32613      3  05:02:30  2023-04-18 2023-04-18 05:02:30
3  32613      5  05:05:30  2023-04-18 2023-04-18 05:05:30
4  32613      6  05:06:30  2023-04-18 2023-04-18 05:06:30
5  32613      8  05:07:30  2023-04-18 2023-04-18 05:07:30
6  32613      9  05:08:30  2023-04-18 2023-04-18 05:08:30
7  32613     11  05:10:30  2023-04-18 2023-04-18 05:10:30
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried that solution like: `dfP['tmp'] = pd.to_datetime(dfP['lnDate'].apply(datetime.strftime,format='%Y-%m-%d') + ' ' +dfP['lnTime'].values.astype(str))` is working, but your solution is way better!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is partially due to your values being encoded as `string` format. You can achieve desired result by first converting to `datetime`, then combining:

```py
df['lnDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['lnDate'])
df['lnTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['lnTime'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time

# Sourced from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39474812/10521959
df['tmp'] = df.apply(lambda r: pd.datetime.combine(r['lnDate'], r['lnTime']), 1)
```

Alternatively, if your data is reliably encoded as a string, you can combine date and time columns then parse as string:

```py
# Sourced from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17978188/10521959
df['tmp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['lnDate'] + ' ' + df['lnTime'])
```

Comment: df['lnTime'] is already `datetime.time` format, not `string`, if it was "vectorize" solution wouldn't work. The problem is no `pd.datetime.combine` function anymore, it's been replaced by `pd.Timestamp.combine` (no idea since when), which is working slightly different way.